# Невозможно работать в команде над проектом созданном на laravel

Tags: git, laravel, bitbucket

После создани проекта и загрузки проекта bitbucket при помощи (git), другие члены команды, которые клонируют себе репозиторий сталкиваются с такой проблемой. Что можно в этом случае предпринять ? HELP
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

1. После того как стянули репозиторий перейдите в директорию проекта и запустите

   ```
   composer install
   ```
2. Следующий шаг — поставить права:
   Папки внутри `storage` должны быть доступны веб-серверу для записи. Если вы устанавливаете фреймворк на Linux или MacOS - открыть папки на запись можно командой

   ```
   chmod -R 777 storage
   ```

Comment: никогда не задавайте доступ 777.

Comment: Даже если это сказанно в официальной документации фреймворка
http://laravel.su/docs/5.2/installation 
Прочитайте здесь раздел "Права на запись" тут на русском . Или же попробуйте поигратся с правами к этой папке и увидите что будет :)

Comment: Это ссылка не официальная документация. На этом сайте, просто кто-то перевал официальную документацию на русский язык. На официальном говорится так: _After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the  storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run. If you are using the Homestead virtual machine, these permissions should already be set._. Там не говорится нужно разрешение для папки 777 [официальная документация Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation)

Comment: Хорошо давайте поставим другие права какие вы предлагаете?